# Creating and Naming Spark DFs Dynamically

Tags: python, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a list of tuples with dataframe names and paths to that dataframe. I want to iterate over the list, read each dataframe and assign it to it's name.

```
paths = [('table1', 's3://my_bucket/data/table1/'), ('table2', 's3://my_bucket/data/table2/')]
```

How do I iterate over this and create each df with the corresponding table name? The below doesn't work cause it creates the dataframe as 'name'.

```
for x in paths:
    name = x[0]
    name = spark.read.parquet(x[1])
```

Answer (score 1):

There are ways to do this, but they are UGLY and error prone.

If at all possible I'd put your dataframes in a dictionary:

```
my_dataframes = {}
for x in paths:
  my_dataframes[x[0]] = spark.read.parquet(x[1])

...

my_dataframes['table1']....
```

But, there is an ugly way -- **DON'T DO THIS** unless you REALLY know what you're doing

`somefile.py`

```
my_dataframes = {}
for x in paths:
  my_dataframes[x[0]] = spark.read.parquet(x[1])
globals().update(my_dataframes)
```

`another_file.py`

```
from .somefile import table1, table2

table1....
```